# Cytoscape.js CoSE layout does not use Weaver

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to speed up my CoSE layouting in Cytoscape.js 3.1.2 via multithreading but setting the weaver option to true does not work, as still only one core is at 100% and the others are idle on Firefox 54, GNOME Shell 3.16.4, SUSE Linux 4.1.39-56. How can I enable weaver correctly?

I include weaver via `<script src="http://weaver.js.org/api/weaver.js-latest/weaver.js"></script>` and execute CoSE via:

```
var cose =
  {
    name:"cose",
    animate: true,
    animationThreshold: 250,
    numIter: 50,
    weaver: true,
  };

cy.layout(cose).run();
```

Comment: CoSE only uses one thread with Weaver, so it will just free up the main/UI thread in the browser.  Only one thread should be busy then --- unless you're animating a lot during the layout and the redraws are expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! How can I check that I included weaver correctly? Is the above mentioned method correct? There is no error or console message if I don't include weaver.

Comment: It needs to be a ref to the lib `weaver: Weaver`

Comment: @maxkfranz where in the documentation is that documented. I can't find it.

Comment: http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/cose